# how to change a text input's value in react js for array?

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the value in the input box in my react js application. I tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61683415/1235167) that uses spread.. but the value still won't change. what am I doing wrong? any help is appreciated..

here's my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [stuffs, setStuffs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getStuffs();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const getStuffs = () => {
    let data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "candy",
        qty: 20
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "book",
        qty: 15
      }
    ];
    setStuffs(data);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log("stuffs1", stuffs);
    setStuffs(
      stuffs.map((item) =>
        item.id === e.target.id ? { ...item, qty: e.target.qty } : item
      )
    );
    console.log("stuffs2", stuffs);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {stuffs.length > 0 ? (
        stuffs.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={item.id}>
            <label>{item.name}</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id={item.id}
              name="qty"
              value={item.qty}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <span>No data</span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and here's the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-firefly-8onx8n?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `event.target.id` defaults to a `string`, you'll need to convert it to number. You can add a `+` in the beginning to easily do that

Your code should look like

```js
stuffs.map((item) =>
      item.id === +e.target.id ? { ...item, qty: e.target.qty } : item
    )
```

Another issue in your code is that you're using `e.target.qty` which is `undefined`. It should be `+e.target.value` instead. (Added `+` for the same reasons to convert it to a number)

Final code should look like

```js
stuffs.map((item) =>
      item.id === +e.target.id ? { ...item, qty: +e.target.value } : item
    )
```

Comment: just a little note for a fellow newbie like me: if there's more than 1 process that needs to be run when `item.id` matches the `e.target.id`, we can use curly brackets in the `map` callback function, we just have to return something (in this case, the `item` variable). so it'll look like this: `stuffs.map((item) => { console.log('blah'); if (item.id === +e.target.id) { item = {...item, qty: +e.target.value}; return item;} });`

Answer (score 1):

`e.target.id` is a string, while `item.id` is a number, so try:

```
setStuffs(
      stuffs.map((item) =>
        item.id === Number(e.target.id) ? { ...item, qty: e.target.qty } : item
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

`event.target.id` evaluates to a string and `item.id` is a number. Thus, `item.id === event.target.id` would always evaluate to false.

use `parseInt()` instead

```
item.id === parseInt(e.target.id, 10)
```